# Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll

Tags: winforms, asp.net-web-api

In the button click event of below code, I'm able to send my data to post action of API Controller now.
**Button Click Event of Windows Form**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.SearchText = textBox1.Text;
        myClass.CountryCode = textBox2.Text;
        string serialisedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass);
        var response = client.UploadString("http://localhost:50232/api/Place/PostSimple", serialisedData);
        var x= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
    }
}
public class MyClass
{
    public string SearchText { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

But while debugging, I'm not able to move after

```
GeocodingResponse geocode = GoogleMaps.Geocode.Query(geocodeRequest);
```

this line of PostSimple action method. and getting the exception in

```
 var response = client.UploadString("http://localhost:50232/api/Place/PostSimple", serialisedData); of Windows form application as
```

*Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll*

*Additional information: The operation has timed out*

**ApiController Code**

```
[HttpPost]
    public List<Place> PostSimple(MyClass value)
    {
        List<Place> list = new List<Place>();
        var geocodeRequest = new GeocodingRequest
        {
           Address = value.SearchText,
           Components = new GeocodingComponents()
            {                   
                Country = value.CountryCode
            }
        };
        try
        {
            GeocodingResponse geocode = GoogleMaps.Geocode.Query(geocodeRequest);
            if (geocode.Status == GoogleMapsApi.Entities.Geocoding.Response.Status.OK)
            {
                TimeZoneRequest request = new TimeZoneRequest();
                request.Location = new Location(geocode.Results.First().Geometry.Location.Latitude, geocode.Results.First().Geometry.Location.Longitude);
                request.Language = "en";
                request.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-60);
                TimeZoneResponse result = GoogleMaps.TimeZone.Query(request);
                var x = System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(result.TimeZoneName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
       return list;
    }
```

**MyClass code**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string SearchText { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue..Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: Side note: Change `throw ex;` to `throw;`. The latter preserves the stack trace. The former resets it which makes tracking down the original culprit of an exception impossible in any exception handling code that occurs later in the stack.

Comment: Please include the exception and it's details as text, not a screen shot. This makes it searchable. Include the full type, the message, and the complete stack trace. Repeat this for any inner exceptions recursively.

Comment: Exception shown in screen shot is expected. My problem is with the line **GeocodingResponse geocode................** of PostSimple action @Igor